pg badger report showing top 10 slowest queries as 'Set extra_float_digits = 3' .. taking nearly 30s each. What does that mean in terms of database
To start with, I am not postgresql dba expert but assisting to help with application performance issue that is using postgresql as a database.
We ran full reporting on the postgresql and analysed it using the pgbadger. It shows top 10 slowest queries as 'set extra_float_digits=3'. These are taking 29-30 seconds to execute as per the report.
Looking at various posts, I can understand this is to do with connections but I can't make a sense out of these queries taking 30 seconds means some of the connections are waiting that long to establish?
Are there any other stats I can focus on pg badger report to assess what may be causing these slow connections or have I got the completely wrong end of the string.
